# How do I stop my variables from printing

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, input

im new to python and wanted to try and make a quick game. I am using the input function so that I can get the user to interact with the game but what im quite confused about is that when I make a variable which contains a input function it prints out automatically. Is there any way to stop the input from printing out while its in the variable.

Note: I also see a problem in my code when I want it to go back to the main menu (printing out the main menu again) but when ill go and do that it will be set to a number 1,2 or 3.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import sys
import winsound

start = str(input("bla"))
menu = int(input("bla0.5")) 
levels_menu = int(input("bla1"))
settings_menu = int(input("bla2"))
credits_menu = int(input("bla3"))

if start == "":
    print(menu)
if menu == "1":
    print(levels_menu)
if menu == "2":
    print(settings_menu)
if menu == "3":
    print(credits_menu)
if menu == "4":
    exit()
```

Hopefully you can help me with my problem!

What I want as output:

```
bla
*I press enter*
bla0.5
*I press 1*
bla2
*I press 4(because that will be the back to main menu number*
bla0.5
(and so forth, you can go through all the menus)
```

python version: 3.3.2

Comment: Of course `print()` prints your choice.. that is exactly what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Where is `menu` defined?

Comment: Sorry I must have deleted it(ill add it now) but pyStarter the print command is what I want to be used but because I created the variables it prints them out if I reach the condition or not (in any of the if statements).

Comment: Could you show a example output and say what you expect it to be? Also you're comparing against strings while menu is set to a int.

Comment: What version of python is this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're confused about when your code gets executed. The `input` function prints its argument and then awaits input. You are defining your variables (`start` and so on) as the return values from the `input` function, so `input` gets called as soon as Python tries to define all those variables.

**What you want** is for those to be *functions* instead of variables. That way, you can call the functions whenever you like, and get the appropriate input at that time. Something like this:

```
def start():
    return str(input('bla\n'))

def menu():
    return int(input('bla0.5\n'))

if start() == '': # CALL the function!
    menuselection = menu() # Call the menu function
    print('menuselection is:', menuselection)

    if menuselection == 1:
        pass # and so forth and so on

--- results ---
bla
    (I press <ENTER>)
bla0.5
1
menuselection is: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want after printing that you are back at your inputs you must make it all into a loop!